# Identifying microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, identification, microprocessor

I am trying to identify a microcontroller in a device and decided to take apart my TI-84 CE Plus calculator.

I am having trouble identifying a specific microcontroller and the manufacturer because the only thing written on it is "ET2017-00 S6266-000". Any ideas of how to identify this device?

[image: writingOnDevicePicturedHere]

Answer (score 0):

TI-84 CE Plus also uses Z-80 variant CPU.
Looking at the flash chip from winnband, it seems like your calculator model is revision M or later.

I am not sure if that MCU is designed and fabricated by TI themselves.
But what I am sure now is, it is using same Z-80 architecture and a little software upgrades and flash chip adding to older brothers.